# Python - Pandas finding the last available row without editing the indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I want to accomplish exactly what is stated here:https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/how-do-i-get-the-current-and-next-greater-value-in-one-select 
but I am not able to reproduce the solution on Pandas. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [ask], [tour], [mcve], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at one of the solutions mentioned in the post you linked:

```
SELECT l.id, l.time, min(r.time) 
FROM idtimes l 
LEFT JOIN idtimes r on (r.id = l.id and r.time > l.time)
GROUP BY l.id, l.time;
```

Say you have a DataFrame with these columns: ID, Left-Time, Right-Time, you first take a subset of your dataset to use and then keep ID and Left-Time as the index for grouping said Dataframe, and use min() to find The smallest Right-Time, as shown here:

```
df = df.loc[df['r_time']>df['l_time']]
df = df.groupby(['id', 'l_time']).aggregate({
     'id': 'first',
     'l_time': 'first',
     'r_time': lambda x: min(x)
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The issue here is that I have 1 column with dates which is basically the date that the id was updated the last time - and from it, I want to derive valid until for each row. Each id can have many changes and only the last one is NULL.

Comment: you should really ask specific questions in the very beginning in order to get help accordingly. Otherwise, time gets wasted on both sides. [link](stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try for input column `x` and output `z`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({"x": [3,4,2,1,7,2,3,5], "y": list("dfghabcd")})

#we need to reverse index, cause expanding() provides open-ended interval from the left, and we need from the right
df=df.reindex(index=df.index[::-1])

df["z"]=df["x"].expanding().apply(lambda x: next(filter(lambda el: el>x[-1], x[::-1]), np.nan), raw=True)
#reverse index back
df=df.reindex(index=df.index[::-1])
```

Outputs:

```py
   x  y    z
0  3  d  4.0
1  4  f  7.0
2  2  g  7.0
3  1  h  7.0
4  7  a  NaN
5  2  b  3.0
6  3  c  5.0
7  5  d  NaN
```

Comment: You have 5k rep, why would you answer this question?

Comment: Cause in its generic form it's quite an interesting one, regardless of how the question itself was phrased ;)

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer here for future viewers:

Problem: View First Comment of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60127749/12450117

I'm not sure what you mean by last row will be NULL - but here's my interpretation of your problem's solution - and there are many other ways to deal with this as well:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['id', 'date']).aggregate('date': lambda x: max(x))
df['valid_until'] = grouped_df['date'].values 
# you can also use pd.merge here to concatenate 
df['valid_until'] = df.apply(lambda x: x if x['date'] < x['valid_until'] else None)
```